# How to go to login page when click submit on the register in angular js

Tags: angularjs

When user would Register then user needs to be login.but here automatically login after registration.How to solve this.

*registration.js*

```
myApp.controller('RegistrationController',
    ['$scope', 'Authentication',
        function($scope, Authentication) {

            $scope.login = function() {
                Authentication.login($scope.user);
            };

            $scope.logout = function() {
                Authentication.logout();
            };

            $scope.register = function() {
                Authentication.register($scope.user);
            }; //register

        }
    ]); //Controller
```

*authentication.js*

```
myApp.factory('Authentication', ['$rootScope', '$location', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseAuth',
    function($rootScope, $location, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth) {

        var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        var auth = $firebaseAuth();
        var myObject;

        auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(authUser) {
            if (authUser) {
                var userRef = ref.child('users').child(authUser.uid);
                var userObj = $firebaseObject(userRef);
                $rootScope.currentUser = userObj;
            } else {
                $rootScope.currentUser = '';
            }
        });

        myObject = {
            login: function(user) {
                auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    user.email,
                    user.password
                ).then(function(user) {
                    $location.path('/success');
                }); //signInWithEmailAndPassword
            }, //login

            logout: function() {
                return auth.$signOut();
            }, //logout

            requireAuth: function() {
                return auth.$requireSignIn();
            }, //require Authentication

            register: function(user) {
                auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                    user.email,
                    user.password
                ).then(function(regUser) {
                    var regRef = ref.child('users')
                        .child(regUser.uid).set({
                            date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                            regUser: regUser.uid,
                            firstname: user.firstname,
                            lastname: user.lastname,
                            email: user.email
                        }); //userinfo
                    myObject.login(user);
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    $rootScope.message = error.message;
                }); //createUserWithEmailAndPassword
            } //register

        }; //return


        return myObject;

    }
]); //factory
```

*register.html*

```
<section class="card register">
    <form name="myform" ng-submit="register()" novalidate>

        <div class="textintro">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <p>To access site features</p>
            <p class="message" ng-show="message">{{ message }}</p>
        </div>

        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-required="true">
            <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myform.firstname.$invalid && myform.firstname.$touched">
                First name required</p>

            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="user.lastname" ng-required="true">
            <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myform.lastname.$invalid && myform.lastname.$touched">
                Last name required</p>

            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true">
            <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myform.email.$invalid && myform.email.$touched">
                Must be a valid email</p>

            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" ng-required="true">
            <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myform.password.$invalid && myform.email.$touched">
                Password is required</p>

        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid">Register</button>
        <p>or <a ng-href="#/login">login</a></p>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question again? I am confused about what you are asking.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You mean to say that whenever the user finishes the registration part than he should be redirected to the login page. Is this your question?

Comment: yes,exactly...here is the demo http://www.nikhilvidyagar.oacerhost.ml/#/login